# Express.js redirect with virtual path

Tags: nginx, express

So I'm setting up a virtual path when pointing at a node.js app in my nginx.conf.  the relevant section looks like so:

```
location /app {
  rewrite /app/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Works great, except when my express app calls a redirect.

As an example, the dev box is running nginx on port 8080, and so the url's to the root of the node app looks like:

```
http://localhost:8080/app
```

When I call a `res.redirect('/app')` from express, the actual redirect goes to:

```
http://localhost/app
```

Since nothing's running on port 80, obviously, this fails.  I also couldn't find any properties of the request object which would let me construct the URL to be an absolute URL, either.  Any ideas short of hardcoding it or making it an environmental variable?

*** edit:  after a little more digging, it looks like the host header is defined as just 'localhost' in this case, while if I connect to the expres app directly, the host header is defined as 'localhost:3000' (where 3000 is the port the node app is listening on).  So how do I change the mapping above to include the port of the nginx server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's because of this line:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

It will set the `Host` header to `localhost` I guess. See the documentation on [proxy_set_header](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_set_header). I think this would do the trick:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

It will pass on the `Host` header from the client request, which should be `localhost:8080`.